# type=Not Acceptable, status=406 Error In Spring Rest For Producing XML

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I'm working on Spring Rest and in my Spring Rest app, if I try to produce json everything is OK. I can see it on browser. There is no error.

But if I want to produce XML, I use produces = "application/xml" or produces=MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE and
I getting this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 23 18:30:51 EEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

My rest code is:

```
package getExample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import pojo.Address;
import pojo.Person;

@RestController
public class GetExampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "getExample",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces=MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
    public List<Person> getExample1(@RequestParam(value = "personId", defaultValue = "0") String id) {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        Person person1 = new Person("1", "ilkay", "günel",
                new Address("Cennet Mah.", "K.Çekmece", "İstanbul", "TÜRKİYE"));
        personList.add(person1);

        Person person2 = new Person("2", "alican", "akkuş",
                new Address("Cennet Mah.", "K.Çekmece", "İstanbul", "TÜRKİYE"));
        personList.add(person2);

        Person person3 = new Person("3", "mustafa", "demir",
                new Address("Cennet Mah.", "K.Çekmece", "İstanbul", "TÜRKİYE"));
        personList.add(person3);

        if (id.equals("0")) {
            return personList;
        }
        else {
            return personList.subList(Integer.parseInt(id)-1, Integer.parseInt(id));
        }
    }
}
```

What is the error? Why can I get XML output? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `jackson-dataformat-xml`'s dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, you may annotate your bean with JAXB annotations.

#### [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html):

> If you have the Jackson XML extension (jackson-dataformat-xml) on the
> classpath, it will be used to render XML responses and the very same
> example as we used for JSON would work.
>
> ...
>
> If Jackson’s XML extension is not available, JAXB (provided by default
> in the JDK) will be used, with the additional requirement to have
> [your class] annotated as @XmlRootElement...
>
> ...
>
> To get the server to render XML instead of JSON you might have to send
> an Accept: text/xml header (or use a browser).

Comment: Thanks - this was exactly what I was missing. Thought spring boot starter included xml support out of box but it does not.