# type=Not Acceptable, status=406 Error In Spring Rest For Producing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: rest, spring-boot

Before, I have problem when producing xml response and I found that I have to add `jackson-dataformat-xml` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204926/type-not-acceptable-status-406-error-in-spring-rest-for-producing-xml)

then I try to add MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE so it can produce url encoded, but same error occurred, type=Not Acceptable, status=406 Error.

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/postJson2Xml", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
ResponseDto postJson2Xml(@RequestBody RequestDto requestDto);
```

the request body will still json, but I want the api to produce urlencoded when I add `Accept application/x-www-form-urlencoded` on the request header.

any suggestion? are there any dependencies that I need to add?

Comment: Please change consumes value as  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". Currently you set its value as  "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE" so that it accepts the request body as JSON.

Comment: thanks for replying, but I do want to consume json then produce urlencoded